# How to modify current insert timestamp script to remove timestamp when cell is cleared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am currently using the following script to add a timestamp to a cell in Column H when cell in Column A is populated.  Problem is, when I delete the contents of Column A the timestamp remains in Column H.  I currently have conditional formatting to hide the timestamp if the cell is empty but I really need the contents to be deleted.  How do I modify my current script to accomplish this?

---

```
 function onEdit(event) {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 if(sheet.getName() == "CHECK OUT" || sheet.getName() == "CHECK IN" || sheet.getName() == "MISC OUT" || sheet.getName() == "MISC IN"){
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 1) { // 1 == column A
    var columnARange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 8, eventRange.getNumRows(), 8);
    var values = columnARange.getValues();
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
       values[i][0] = new Date();
}
columnARange.setValues(values);
   }
 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name=="CHECK OUT" || name== "CHECK IN" || name== "MISC OUT" || name=="MISC IN"){  
    if(rg.columnStart==1) {
      var vA=rg.getValues();
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
        if(vA[i][0]) {
          sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,8).setValue(new Date());
        }else{
          sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,8).setValue('');    
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure that you get the last edit.  It turns that the `e.value` in `if(e.value && e.value.length>0)` is really important because e.value is not defined when you delete cell contents.  It took me a while to figure that out.  It's really helpful to have the new executions page.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean in your last comment.

Also, I ran in to a problem with this.  If you delete the contents in column A cell by cell it works but if you highlight several cells in Column A and select delete it does NOT work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: When I debug it is giving me the following error:  TypeError: Cannot read property "range" from undefined. (line 2, file "TimeStamp".  This section is highlighted:    var rg=e.range;

Comment: I hope you realize that you can't run this function without an event object.  You have to do your testing by edit the appropriate sheet or you could possible recreate the event object.

Comment: That makes sense now on the debug error.  Thank you

Comment: Any suggestion on the timestamp not deleting if several are deleted at once?

Comment: I changed the answer.