# Timestamp is generated when cell is not empty. If blank, timestamp is cleared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

What I am trying to create a script which is when you enter a value in column 2, it generates a timestamp and timestamp clears itself if cell is blank.

I trying to combine "my code" and "other code".
The Problem is, when I clear the cell in Column 2 the timestamp still remains in Column 1.

How do I fix my code to make it work?

If anybody can help, power to you.

EDIT: already answered by @Raserhin

My code: [original source](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/18439710?msgid=18439710&authuser=0)

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
        watchCols = [2],
        offsetCol = [-1],
        ind = watchCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
        if (s.getName() !== "work" || ind === -1) return;
    e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind])
        .setValue(new Date());
}
```

Other code I trying to combine with.
[How to modify current insert timestamp script to remove timestamp when cell is cleared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259009/how-to-modify-current-insert-timestamp-script-to-remove-timestamp-when-cell-is-c)

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  if(name=="CHECK OUT" || name== "CHECK IN" || name== "MISC OUT" || name=="MISC IN"){  
    if(rg.columnStart==1) {
      var vA=rg.getValues();
      for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
        if(vA[i][0]) {
          sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,8).setValue(new Date());
        }else{
          sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,8).setValue('');    
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My combined code:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zGg9TUFQcqapG6-ZxB3CPJNwFsisxT98gbkrqU0Wns/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var rg=e.range;
    var sh=e.range.getSheet();
    var name=sh.getName();
    var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
        watchCols = [2],
        offsetCol = [-1],
        ind = watchCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
        if (s.getName() !== "work" || ind === -1) return;
    e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind])
        .setValue(new Date());
    if(rg.columnStart==1) {
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      if(vA[i][0]) {
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,8).setValue(new Date());
      }else{
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,8).setValue('');    
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:
Thanks to @Raserhin for noticing my mistake.

```
//Working code
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
      watchCols = [2],
      offsetCol = [-1],
      ind = watchCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
  if (s.getName() !== "work" || ind === -1) return;
  e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind])
  .setValue(new Date());
  if(rg.columnStart==2) { // Change 1 to 2
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      if(vA[i][0]) {
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue(new Date()); // Change 8 to 1 
      }else{
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue('');    // Change 8 to 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and tested your "combined code" and there are only two small details.

In the `if` statement to check the edited column, in sheets start at index 1.

And also you to change the values of the date you have an 8 as the column that don't make sense.

Editing that makes your code works for me:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var name=sh.getName();
  var s = e.source.getActiveSheet(),
      watchCols = [2],
      offsetCol = [-1],
      ind = watchCols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart)
  if (s.getName() !== "work" || ind === -1) return;
  e.range.offset(0, offsetCol[ind])
  .setValue(new Date());
  if(rg.columnStart==2) { // Change 1 to 2
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      if(vA[i][0]) {
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue(new Date()); // Change 8 to 1 
      }else{
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).setValue('');    // Change 8 to 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried @JPV answer and doesn't work me.

Comment: thanks it worked. I did not notice I have forget to change the values from the previous script. Thanks for the correction.